# How to merge elements of dataframes of different sizes containded in a list [R]?

Tags: r, merge, lapply

I have a list composed by 5 `data.frames` of different sizes, each `data.frame` has two variables, `Group.1` and `x`, i would like to merge those data.frames by the `Group.1` variables. Of course I expect `NA` values to be generated.

Example:

```
Group.1 = c(01, 03, 05) 
x = c(2000, 4000, 5000) 
a <- data.frame(Group.1, x)

Group.1 = c(03, 05) 
x = c(400, 500) 
b <- data.frame(Group.1, x)

Group.1 = c(01, 05) 
x = c(2000,2500) 
c <- data.frame(Group.1, x)

lst <- list(a,b,c)

variables <- as.numeric(c(1:3))
test2 <- lapply(variables, function(t) merge((data.frame(lst[t])), by="Group.1"))
```

An extra note: I would like to use apply (or lapply) to test it with different list sizes.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Reduce()` works nicely with `merge()` on a list.

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = "Group.1", all = TRUE), lst)
#   Group.1  x.x x.y    x
# 1       1 2000  NA 2000
# 2       3 4000 400   NA
# 3       5 5000 500 2500
```

Comment: Thank you Richard, you made my Friday nicer and especially shorter... ;-)